# gitlab ci vue3 [vite]: Rollup failed

Tags: gitlab, vuejs3

When I push my project, gitlab runner launches the following commands:

- npm install
- npm run build

build command fails but i don't know why. When i try to build in remote server, it works.

did you have any ideas please ?

I have 2 servers updating, only one fails (windows server)

> [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "vee-validate" from
> "src/plugins/vee-validate.js". This is most likely unintended because
> it can break your application at runtime. If you do want to
> externalize this module explicitly add it to
> `build.rollupOptions.external` error during build: Error: [vite]:
> Rollup failed to resolve import "vee-validate" from
> "src/plugins/vee-validate.js". This is most likely unintended because
> it can break your application at runtime. If you do want to
> externalize this module explicitly add it to
> `build.rollupOptions.external`